# Can't install python package-error in virtualenv: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Tags: python, linux, pytorch, virtualenv

I am using python in windows subsystem ubuntu 20.04.3, I created a virtual environment and installed **python 3.7** (ubuntu **system has python 3.8**), I need to install the python package `torch-sparse`, however, after I ran `pip install torch-scatter -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.4.0+cpu.html`, I had following error:

```
   /home/alva/python/foo-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/aten_interned_strings.h:1001:9: note: ‘c10::attr::value’ declared here
     1001 | _(attr, value) \
          |         ^~~~~
    /home/alva/python/foo-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/interned_strings.h:373:35: note: in definition of macro ‘DEFINE_SYMBOL’
      373 |   namespace ns { constexpr Symbol s(static_cast<unique_t>(_keys::ns##_##s)); }
          |                                   ^
    /home/alva/python/foo-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/interned_strings.h:204:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘FORALL_ATTR_BASE_SYMBOLS’
      204 |   FORALL_ATTR_BASE_SYMBOLS(_)        \
          |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    /home/alva/python/foo-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/interned_strings.h:374:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘FORALL_NS_SYMBOLS’
      374 | FORALL_NS_SYMBOLS(DEFINE_SYMBOL)
          | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1
    ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /home/alva/python/foo-3.7/bin/python3.7 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-bd2qx3dj/torch-sparse/setup.py'"'"';
__file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-bd2qx3dj/torch-sparse/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record /tmp/pip-record-ppnxm3yh/install-record.txt
--single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/alva/python/foo-3.7/include/site/python3.7/torch-sparse Check the logs for full command output. WARNING: You are using pip version
20.1.1; however, version 22.0.3 is available. You should consider upgrading via the '/home/alva/python/foo-3.7/bin/python3.7 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

and

```
 In file included from /home/alva/python/foo-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/Dimname.h:5,
                   from /home/alva/python/foo-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/NamedTensor.h:4,
                   from /home/alva/python/foo-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/TensorBody.h:20,
                   from /home/alva/python/foo-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/Tensor.h:11,
                   from /home/alva/python/foo-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/Context.h:4,
                   from /home/alva/python/foo-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/ATen.h:5,
                   from /home/alva/python/foo-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/types.h:3,
                   from /home/alva/python/foo-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/dataloader_options.h:4,
                   from /home/alva/python/foo-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/dataloader/base.h:3,
                   from /home/alva/python/foo-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/dataloader/stateful.h:3,
                   from /home/alva/python/foo-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data/dataloader.h:3,
                   from /home/alva/python/foo-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/data.h:3,
                   from /home/alva/python/foo-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/all.h:4,
                   from /home/alva/python/foo-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/torch/extension.h:4,
                   from csrc/cpu/convert_cpu.h:3,
                   from csrc/cpu/convert_cpu.cpp:1:   /home/alva/python/foo-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/aten_interned_strings.h:1001:9: note: ‘c10::attr::value’ declared here    1001 | _(attr, value) \
        |         ^~~~~   /home/alva/python/foo-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/interned_strings.h:373:35: note: in definition of macro ‘DEFINE_SYMBOL’
    373 |   namespace ns { constexpr Symbol s(static_cast<unique_t>(_keys::ns##_##s)); }
        |                                   ^   /home/alva/python/foo-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/interned_strings.h:204:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘FORALL_ATTR_BASE_SYMBOLS’
    204 |   FORALL_ATTR_BASE_SYMBOLS(_)        \
        |   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   /home/alva/python/foo-3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/include/ATen/core/interned_strings.h:374:1: note: in expansion of macro ‘FORALL_NS_SYMBOLS’
    374 | FORALL_NS_SYMBOLS(DEFINE_SYMBOL)
        | ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~   error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1   ----------------------------------------   ERROR: Failed building wheel for torch-sparse
```

I tried codes

```
sudo apt-get install python3.7-dev

sudo apt-get install libpq-dev python-dev libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev libffi-dev

sudo apt-get install python3.7-dev

sudo apt install build-essential

pip install torch-sparse -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.4.0/torch_sparse-0.5.1+cpu-cp37-cp37m-linux_x86_64.whl
```

But I still get the same error. I have torch 1.4.0+cpu but I don't think torch version is the problem.

How can I get rid of this error?  Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hello I finally solved my issue, so I post my solution here.

First I need to clarify that I need to install torch-sparse, and there's typo in my command(I copy paste the code for torch-scatter by mistake). But the error message is correct.

What I did is that I unintalled ubuntu 20.04 and **installed ubuntu 18.04**, which has **default python 3.6.9**. Then I proceed to create a virtualenv using default python version, and just use `pip install torch-sparse==0.5.1` and it works now.